# javascript setInterval() collision between the delay and execution time

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval

Is there a way to avoid the conflict between the delay and execution time if the time of execution was longer than the delay using `setInterval()`?

For example:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  // some code that takes 300 ms to be executed
  // which it's longer than the delay 200 ms
}, 200);
```

I already found the alternate way, which is to use `setTimeout()` with recursion to ensure that the delay will start immediately after the function is executed, but my question is about `setInterval()`, not replacing it with `setTimeout()`

Comment: So do not use interval, there is no way to change it. You know you should use setTimeout. Other option is to kill the process/logic if the previous code has not completed.

Comment: You can override setInterval function with your own implementation. 
No other options I guess.

Comment: I know that I can override it, I just wanted to know if there is any technique to use setInterval without worry about the execution time.. anyway thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your concern.

Javascript is always single-threaded that means that in time of execution of the function called by setInterval no other function will be executed and no re-run of setInterval may happen!

Naturally if in your setInterval called function you use deferred calls you enable the function to finish and be executed again.
To protect against such problem you may use a simple semaphore like:

```
var inProcessing = false ;
setInterval(function(){
  // some code that takes 300 ms to be executed
  // which it's longer than the delay 200 ms
     if (!inProcessing){
        inProcessing = true ;
        $http.get(...).then(function(){inProcessing = false;...},
                            function(){inProcessing = false;...});
     }
  }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using `setInterval`, only `setTimeout`. If your problem is the lack of easy cancellation of the `setTimeout` method, you can use the following:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function runMe(){
    // some code that takes 300 ms to be executed

    timeout = setTimeout(runMe, 200);
}, 200);

// somewhere else

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: that's the only way I found is to use setTimeout as you tell. @SeinopSys, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nested setTimeout instead of setInterval. Hope you enjoy ! 
https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you just want to postpone a cycle of `setInterval` if the code from a previous run isn't complete.

```
var starts = 0;
var ends = 0;
function myFunc () {
   starts++;
   //doStuff
   ends++;
}

setInterval(function () {
   if (starts === ends) {
      myFunc();
   }
}, 200);
```